# Rails3 display HASH value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

Im trying to use the Ancestry gem. How can I display a value from a HASH to screen from a HASH that looks like this:

```
{ #<TreeNode id: 100018, name: "Stinky", ancestry: nil>
    { #<TreeNode id: 100019, name: "Crunchy", ancestry: "100018">
       { #<TreeNode id: 100020, name: "Squeeky", ancestry: "100018/100019">
       {}
       }
    }
}
```

Thank you...

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this for debugging purposes, in your view file, you can use the 'debug' helper method

```
# app/views/pages/index.html.erb

<%= debug(@page) %>
```

assuming that hash is in the @page variable.

## EDIT

I've never used the ancestry gem before, but reading its [github page ("Navigating your tree"](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)) maybe you can do this in your view

```
<%= @record.parent.name %>
<% for descendant in @record.descendants %>
  <%= descendant.name %>
```

Comment: Im trying to use the ancestry gem: